# Can up arrow command history for oh-my-zsh narrow down history by options/parameters given to the command

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh

Not sure I'm wording the question very well, but an example is worth a thousand words of mine. eg., using oh-my-zsh :

```
git <up arrow>
```

Will cycle up all the `git` commands I have used...

```
git rebase brancha
git commit foo
git rebase branchb
etc
```

Is there a way to limit that history to the second/third word given. eg.

```
git rebase <up arrow>
```

To only cycle through `git rebase` commands :

```
git rebase brancha
git rebase branchb
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for the zle widget [`history-beginning-search-backward`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-history_002dbeginning_002dsearch_002dbackward), which is not bound to a key by default.

You can bind this command to a key, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> (and the symmetric command on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>). Keychords like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> send different escape sequences on different terminals, so check what yours sends by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>; `\e` represents an escape character (displayed as `^[` by most terminals) which is the first character of all escape sequences.

```
bindkey '\e[1;5A' history-beginning-search-backward
bindkey '\e[1;5B' history-beginning-search-forward
```